# My code doesn't works for more than two digit numbers:

Tags: python-3.x

My code doesn't works for more than two digit numbers:
  Its simple code to find the minimum and maximum value in a list

```
lew = [input("Enter somthing") for i in range(1, 11)]
mini = lew[0]
maxi = lew[0]
print(mini)
print(maxi)
for j in range(len(lew)):
  if lew[j] < mini:
    mini = lew[j]

  if lew[j] > maxi:
    maxi = lew[j]

print(mini)
print(maxi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string in Python 3, therefore your code uses string comparison (`'10' < '110'`). You should convert each input to an `int` (or `float` for that matter):

`lew = [int(input("Enter somthing")) for i in range(1, 11)]`

Also keep in mind that this list comprehension will break if user's input can't be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull. You're comparing **strings**, not floats/integers, etc, some number type. You're doing a lexiographic comparison!

Let's check:

> The comparison uses lexicographical ordering: first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted.

You have to convert your list to integers - use

```
lew = [int(input("Enter somthing")) for i in range(1, 11)]
```